Probability student scores higher than other students in a quiz

Alan, Barry and Calvin are given the same multiple-choice quiz to answer. The
quiz has $10$ questions, each provided with four possible answers, of which only one
is correct. All $10$ questions are of equal value. Alan knows eight of the correct
answers, Barry knows seven, and Calvin knows six. All of them then answer the
remaining questions by sheer guesswork independently. No penalty is imposed on
a wrong answer. What is the probability that Calvin scores higher than both Alan
and Barry in the quiz?

So I thought of considering two cases: (i) When Calvin guesses three questions correctly, and (ii) When Calvin guesses four questions correctly.
This is because even if Alan guesses none of the two questions correctly, Calvin would still need to guess at least three questions correctly in order to score higher than both Alan and Barry.
Therefore, using conditional probability:
Let $C$ be the number of correct guesses Calvin makes.
$P(\text{Calvin wins}) = P(\text{Calvin wins } |C = 3)P(C = 3) + P(\text{Calvin wins } |C = 4 )P(C = 4)$
When Calvin guesses three correctly,
The probability of him guessing three correctly:
$$(C = 3) = {4 \choose 3}(\frac{1}{4})^3\times \frac{3}{4}$$
The probability of Alan guessing none correctly and Barry guessing at most one correctly is given by,
$$P(\text{Calvin wins } |C = 3 ) = \frac{9}{16} \times \frac{30}{64}$$
When Calvin guesses all four correctly:
The probability of him guessing three correctly,
$$(C = 4) = {4 \choose 4}(\frac{1}{4})^4$$
The probability of Alan guessing at most one correctly and Barry guessing at most two correctly is given by,
$$P(\text{Calvin wins } |C = 4 ) = \frac{15}{16} \times \frac{37}{64}$$
Therefore,
$$ P(\text{Calvin wins }) = ({4 \choose 3}(\frac{1}{4})^3 \times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{9}{16} \times \frac{30}{64}) + ({4 \choose 4}(\frac{1}{4})^4 \times \frac{15}{16} \times \frac{37}{64})$$
$$P(C) = \frac{3795}{262144} \approx 1.45\%$$
Is my answer correct?

Your notation is a bit confusing,  as you appear to use $C$ to mean both Calvin's number of correct guesses and the event that he wins.

To simplify the writing: in the end you will need the full distribution of scores, so I'd just write all that out.  Once you have that table you can read the answer off. That will make it easier to check a well

let me fix it real quick

I'm pretty sure you have a mistake.
For a binomial distribution of n events, $P(successes=x)={n\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$, and not ${n\choose x}p^x$.
Therefore, the cumulative $P(successes\geq x )=\sum_{j=x}^n{n\choose j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}$.
Can you take it from here?
